# Warn targeting a higher framework than project’s current target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I can't resolve warning.

> could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1".

My VS has those frameworks:
[image]

The project framework is set up to 4.7.2
[image]

I also found this strings when I open the project like code

```
<ItemGroup>
<BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
  <Install>true</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
  <Install>false</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can try to edit the modeling project file to ignore target framework version mismatchest. Here is a [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/reference-could-not-be-resolved-error-when-validating-your-architecture-using-visual-studio-architecture-modeling-tools/) you can refer to.